# Asynchronous Video Streaming Android

Tags: android, video-streaming

I have been working on video playback of progressive videos from my android application. I am able to stream videos from internet.

But the video starts after buffering the whole data.

Here is the code I am using-

```
private static final String MOVIEURL = "movieUrl";
private static final String TAG = "VideoPlayerActivity";
private int mVideoWidth;
private int mVideoHeight;
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private SurfaceView mPreview;
private SurfaceHolder holder;
private String path;
private Bundle extras;
private boolean mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;
private boolean mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;    

protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.mediaplayer_2);
    mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
    holder = mPreview.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    extras = getIntent().getExtras();
}

 private void playVideo(String movieUrl) {
        doCleanUp();
        try {
            path=movieUrl;


            // Create a new media player and set the listeners
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
            mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            return false;
        }
    }

   public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer arg0, int percent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBufferingUpdate percent:" + percent);

    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCompletion called");
    }


  private void doCleanUp() {
        mVideoWidth = 0;
        mVideoHeight = 0;
        mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;
        mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;
    }

  public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onVideoSizeChanged called");
        if (width == 0 || height == 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "invalid video width(" + width + ") or height(" + height + ")");
            return;
        }
        mIsVideoSizeKnown = true;
        mVideoWidth = width;
        mVideoHeight = height;
        if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
            startVideoPlayback();
        }
    }

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaplayer) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared called");
        mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = true;
        if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
            startVideoPlayback();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder, int i, int j, int k) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged called");

    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed called");
    }


    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated called");
       playVideo(extras.getString(MOVIEURL));



    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseMediaPlayer();
        doCleanUp();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        releaseMediaPlayer();
        doCleanUp();
    }

    private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    private void startVideoPlayback() {
        Log.v(TAG, "startVideoPlayback");
        holder.setFixedSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
```

This code is working fine, but not playing before the whole video gets buffered.

Is there anyway we can stream the video while buffering it in the background.

Thanks.

Comment: Use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: Using AsyncTask to show the progress dialog. Can you please tell me,using it for streaming.

Comment: Remove `startVideoPlayback();` in `onPrepared()` and call it in `playVideo()`, it should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks  yorkw. Your comment was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
mMediaPlayer.prepare();
```

Use :

```
mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```